# How can I prevent Telegram from notifying me about contacts that recently joinedTelegram

Tags: telegram

I don't want to get any message when a contact starts to use telegram. In the notification settings switched off notifying me when a contact has joined telegram, but my telegram chat history is still full of messages such as "John Smith uses Telegram now!".

And the telegram icon also shows that there are new messages even if I got no real new messages but only some contacts joined Telegram.

This is really annoying, especially now when many people start using telegram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can stop these by going to Settings > Notifications and Sounds > Contact joined Telegram. Turn that option off and you won't get notifications about new contacts joining.

-[Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-the-notification-in-Telegram-When-a-new-contact-joined-Telegram-I-get-a-notification-saying-the-contact-has-joined-Telegram)

Comment: This is what I did as described in my questions, but I still get the messages in my telegram chat history, but the answer you linked from Quora is more detailed. Unfortunately, it is not possible to getr the desired effect without other side-effects, one would get when disabling synchronisation of contacts.